# How to include Ajax into a View if I don't use the layout.html in Web2py

Tags: web2py

I am using an html template for a project where I don't use the the `layout.html`. I deleted the `{{extend 'layout.html'}}` from the View, however, I still want to use the `views/web2py_ajax.html`.

I tried a couple of things: first I tried to put `{{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}` in my `new_template.html` then `{{include}}` but that wasn't working.

Then, I copied the code form the `views/web2py_ajax.html` file into my `new_template.html` View and that didn't seem to work.

When I say `new_template.html` I mean the html template I use that is not the `layout.html`.

In the `head` of the `new_template.html`, under all the `css` links and `js` scripts of the `new_template.html` I placed this:

```
{{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}
    {{
  response.files.insert(0,URL('static','css/web2py.css'))
  response.files.insert(1,URL('static','css/bootstrap.min.css'))
  response.files.insert(2,URL('static','css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css'))
  response.files.insert(3,URL('static','css/web2py_bootstrap.css'))
  }}
```

Then, in the `body` of the `new_template.html` I put:

```
{{include}}
```

I tested the `form` `submit` and the error messages are plain black text instead of the error messages in the red background box with white text. I know there must be a better way to test this but I am a little bit lost. What is the best way to do this?

I'd appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you mean by "wasn't working" (i.e., what did you try, and what were the results; any details regarding diagnosis)? You may need to show more of your view code. Also, do you have the assets loaded by web2py_ajax.html in the right places (in particular, jQuery and web2py.js)? And make sure you are not loaded jQuery twice.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks very much for your reply. I edited my post and added additional details about the view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must finalize `response.files` prior to including web2py_ajax.html, as that view includes the `response.include_files()` call, which actually generates the HTML to load all the files in the page. So, it should be:

```
{{
  response.files.insert(0,URL('static','css/web2py.css'))
  response.files.insert(1,URL('static','css/bootstrap.min.css'))
  response.files.insert(2,URL('static','css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css'))
  response.files.insert(3,URL('static','css/web2py_bootstrap.css'))
}}
{{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}
```

You must also make sure all of the static assets loaded by web2py_ajax.html are actually available (e.g., web2py.js must be in the /static/js folder of the application).

Finally, the view of the particular page you are loading must start with:

```
{{extend 'new_template.html'}}
```

Although you don't have to use the layout.html layout from the scaffolding application, if you are creating your own layout from scratch, it is still recommended that you copy some of the code from the head of layout.html. It is also a good idea to start with the scaffolding application as a base and then remove what you don't need -- that way you'll have the required static assets in the right place from the beginning.

Comment: thanks very much for this, I appreciate it. Now, I understand what I was doing wrong. Thanks again!